# jQuery autocomplete - include description

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

How can I add to the results which are displayed smaller text with a description? I have the description in the array of data that autocomplete is using. I can call this by using the .result function and calling item.description

So right now I see a list:

```
Item1<br />
Item2<br />
Item3<br />
```

I'd like to have it

```
Item1<br />
&nbsp;description<br />
Item2<br />
&nbsp;description<br />
Item3<br />
&nbsp;description<br />

var results = new Array();

function prep(){
$("#searchbox").autocomplete(results,{

  formatItem: function(item) {
    return item.title;


  }
}).result(function(event, item) {
  location.href = item.url;
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){


                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "links2.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(xml) {

                        // Count elements
                        var count = $(xml).find('ROW').length;
                        // Create Array of correct length
                        //window.results = new Array(count);
                        // Set array variable
                        var num_row = 0;
                        //data string
                        var datastring = "";

                        //start of find block
                        $(xml).find('ROW').each(function() {

                            var title = $(this).find('SC_DF_FIELD_1').text();
                            var url = $(this).find('SC_DF_FIELD_2').text();
                            var support_url = $(this).find('SC_DF_FIELD_3').text();
                            var description = $(this).find('SC_DF_FIELD_4').text();
                            var contacts = $(this).find('SC_DF_FIELD_5').text();
                            //clean up xml variables
                            url = url.substring(url.indexOf('>') + 1, url.indexOf('/a') - 1);
                            support_url = support_url.substring(support_url.indexOf('>') + 1, support_url.indexOf('/a') - 1); /*need to clean up contacts search later */

                            results[num_row] = {'title': title, 'url': url, 'support_url': support_url, 'description': description, 'contacts': contacts};
                            num_row++

                          //  $('<div class="items"></div>').html('<a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                        });
                        //end of find block
                        prep();
                    }
                });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="page-wrap">
<FORM autocomplete="off"><INPUT id="searchbox" type="text"/>
</FORM></DIV>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In case you don't know this, the correct method for creating a list is with the `li` list item elements with `ul` unordered or `ol` ordered lists, not with a paragraph of text separated by line breaks

Comment: that was just experimental code to see what would happen. I meant to remove it before I posted it. It doesn't have anything to do with the question. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

added the description to the return statement. DOH!